# How to do OFTYPE ONLY in EF Code First with Linq?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, ef-code-first

When using traditional Entity Framework and querying with ESQL, you can use OFTYPE with ONLY to only return base types.

See:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399295.aspx

In Entity Framework Code First, I have inheritance set up where B is a subtype of A.  Performing `MyContext.Set<A>().OfType<A>()` still returns elements of type B.  Ideally, I would like to call `MyContext.Set<A>().OfOnlyType<A>()` and it would translate the same way as when using ESQL's OFTYPE ONLY.

I also found I can use the `is` operator in a where statement, but again, that will return both A and B entities.

How can I write a linq expression that will filter to only elements of type A?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to get only `A` instances directly (equivalent to `ONLY`) in Linq-to-entities unless you somehow exclude derived instances from the result set. For example:

```
var list = MyContext.Set<A>().Where(a => !(a is B)).ToList();
```

Comment: ESQL's `OFTYPE` has an optional keyword `ONLY` mentioned in the question, which changes the behaviour. The question is how to convert that to LINQ, when it's possible in ESQL. Your answer is right, except for the "Your understanding is wrong" remark and an unnecessary explanation.

Comment: Say there were several dervied types.  I would have to exclude them all?  I wonder what the ONLY keyword in ESQL does behind the scenes to not have this issue?

Comment: Yes you will have to. ESQL is more powerful query language then Linq-to-entities but due to Linq hype it was mostly deprecated. `ONLY` works in similar way as manually specifying where condition. Queries are not same but approach is similar.

Comment: Barbara Liskov is spinning on her... bed.